# opengl multitexturing for a starter

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, textures

i have animation project which requires multiple textures ,i intend to see all of them yet only 1 texture covers on my model.i cant see all tga files on the object.

```
    GLuint LoadTexture(char *TexName)
  {
TGAImg Img;        // Image loader

  // Load our Texture
   if(Img.Load(TexName)!=IMG_OK)
    return -1;

   glGenTextures(1,textures);            // Allocate space for texture
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textures[0]); // Set our Tex handle as current

   // Create the texture
    if(Img.GetBPP()==24)
     glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,3,Img.GetWidth(),Img.GetHeight(),0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,Img.GetImg());
    else if(Img.GetBPP()==32)
     glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,4,Img.GetWidth(),Img.GetHeight(),0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,Img.GetImg());
    else
     return -1;

   // Specify filtering and edge actions
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP);

   return textures[0];
  }

void Draw()
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glGenTextures(17,textures);

    for (int i = 0; i<17; i++){
         textures[i] = LoadTexture(textureNames[i   
         glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i]);
    }

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);                   
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,triangleArr);              
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);                  
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, TotalConnectedTriangles); 
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);                  
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);  
}

void initialize () 
{
    glViewport(0, 0, 500, 500);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0, 1, 0.1, 1000.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH );
    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    
    textures[textureIndex] = LoadTexture(textureNames[textureIndex]);   
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[textureIndex]);

    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);


    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);    
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, textureArr);

}
</code>`enter code here`
```

i am not sure if i need to post my obj file?

Comment: what is obj file? what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the docs of [`glActiveTexture`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glActiveTexture.xml). Calling `glBindTexture` in a loop doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: when i try to use glActiveTexture, it says undefined.and glee.h doesnt include it?maybe its in another library? glut.h <GL/gl.h <GL/glu.h> <glm/glm.hpp>

Comment: neither will glActiveTexture do what you think it does ;)

Comment: Yeah, I'm just nudging him in the direction of learning about OpenGL multi-texturing rather than posting full-blown code since, based on his code, there's some pretty big concept misunderstandings of the topic. If `glActiveTexture` is not in your .h file, then you need to use something like `GLEW`: http://glew.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong for many reasons :

1. if the draw() function is your rendering callback, then you are going to create a set of textures and load data into them. It is wrong, since you need to do it only once.
2. LoadTexture() is going to create a new texture, and load it with data from a file. This is wrong, since you already created 17 textures i function
3. Then you are binding each texture in a loop, and only the last is going to be active
4. Then you dump all vertexes from a VBO to be rendered. I do not see where you initialized them, but they are going to use only the last binded texture.
5. You have another call to LoadTexture() in the initialize(). Actually all textures should be generated and loaded there

Comment: @alp not really. Just google for opengl texture example, and you'll get million hits